# Different Approach for Lead&Lag- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Reposting, because my earlier post got accidentally deleted while editing. I'm querying from a table to create a reporting table for Renewal accounts.

I'm looking to find a `Prior_PolicyNumber` and the `Next_Policynumber` for a given `MasterPolicyNumber` which I have name as 
`CurrentMasterPolicyNumber`.

```
With PolicyTable as 
(   select  Region, 
            SubmissionNumber, 
            MasterPolicyNumber, 
            isnull(PolicyNumber, SUBSTRING(MasterPolicyNumber, 8,6)) as PolicyNumber, 
            NewRenewal, 
            EffectiveDate, 
            ExpiryDate, 
            Coverage, 
            InsuredName
            from Policy_Dtl 
            ---group by PolicyNumber

), 
PolicyFinal as (        
select  
        a.Region,
        a.SubmissionNumber,
        a.PolicyNumber, 
        LAG(a.MasterPolicyNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY a.PolicyNumber  ORDER BY a.EffectiveDate) as Prior_MasterPolicyNumber,
        prior_policies2.MasterPolicyNumber as prior2_MasterPolicyNumber,
        a.MasterPolicyNumber as CurrentMasterPolicyNumber,                                  
        LEAD(a.MasterPolicyNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY a.PolicyNumber ORDER BY a.EffectiveDate) as  Next_MasterPolicyNumber, 
        a.NewRenewal, 
        a.EffectiveDate, 
        a.ExpiryDate,
        a.Coverage, 
        a.InsuredName
from PolicyTable a
left join   PolicyTable as prior_policies2 on  left(a.SubmissionNumber,len(a.SubmissionNumber)-3) = prior_policies2.MasterPolicyNumber 
)
select b.Region,
        b.SubmissionNumber,
        b.PolicyNumber,
        coalesce(b.Prior_MasterPolicyNumber,b.prior2_MasterPolicyNumber) as PriorMasterPolicyNumber,
        b.CurrentMasterPolicyNumber,                                    
        b.Next_MasterPolicyNumber, 
        b.NewRenewal, 
        b.EffectiveDate, 
        b.ExpiryDate,
        b.Coverage, 
        b.InsuredName

from PolicyFinal b
```

`PolicyNumber` column is the middle part of each Policy number.

The existing Lead and Lag approach doesn't return the correct results. When I do the lead and Lag over policy number, it returns incorrect results. Because, sometimes, the `Policynumber` would be the same for different accounts.

So I'm looking for modified approach where

1. considering Policynumber and
2. then matching the effective date of the current masterpolicy number to the Expiry date of the previous record and vice versa to find the Next_PolicyNumber
3. then the Region of current should match with the prior and next_policynumber
4. The row that has New, should not have a prior policy number

In the sample example, I'm looking to group all Avalon bay together and find out its prior and Next policy numbers.

[image]

Another sitution when the EffectiveDate Date is 1 less or greater than the ExpiryDate of the previous policy.

[image]

I wouldn't be taking the Insured name as a filter because the names might change in some point in time.

My desired results should be like this . Thanks in advance

[image]

Sample Data:

```
                        --===== If the test table already exists, drop it
                         IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#mytable') IS NOT NULL
                            DROP TABLE #mytable

                    --===== Create the test table with 
                     CREATE TABLE #mytable 
                            (

                            Region nvarchar(300), 
                            SubmissionNumber nvarchar(300),
                            MasterPolicyNumber nvarchar(300),
                            PolicyNumber nvarchar(100), 
                            NewRenewal nvarchar(100), 
                            EffectiveDate Date, 
                            ExpiryDate Date, 
                            Coverage nvarchar(100), 
                            InsuredName nvarchar(300)
                            )

                        SET DATEFORMAT DMY

                    --===== Insert the test data into the test table
                     INSERT INTO #mytable 
                           (Region,SubmissionNumber,MasterPolicyNumber,PolicyNumber, NewRenewal,EffectiveDate,ExpiryDate,Coverage,InsuredName)
                     SELECT 'Asia',         '14-12-10-000001-01','47-ACA-000001-01','000001','New',     '2014-12-25',   '2015-12-25','','CPC Corporation, Taiwan (CPC)' UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'Asia',         '15-10-10-006366-01','47-ACA-000001-02','000001','Renewal','2015-12-25','2016-12-25','','CPC Corporation, Taiwan (CPC)' UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'North America','13-05-01-000220-01','42-PRP-000001-01','000001','New',     '2013-05-15','2014-05-15','PRP','AvalonBay Communities,Inc.' UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'North America','14-04-01-009463-01','42-XPR-000001-02','000001','Renewal','2014-05-15','2015-05-15','XPR','AvalonBay Communities, Inc.' UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'North America','13-05-01-000220-01','42-XPR-000001-03','000001','Renewal','2015-05-15','2016-05-15','XPR','AvalonBay Communities, Inc.' UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'North America','42-XPR-000001-03-01','42-XPR-000001-04','000001','Renewal','2016-05-15','2017-05-15','XPR','AvalonBay Communities, Inc.'
```

Comment: Is it possible to `JOIN` to an account table or otherwise get the account number?  It seems that if you could include account number in your partitions it would work.

Comment: I do not have account table for this .. The only combinations that I would work will be based on NewRenewal, EffectiveDate=previous year Expiry Date and Then Region=Previous Row region (of same account)

Comment: What if two accounts share the same renewal range?  (ie. both have `effectivedate = '2014-05-15'` and `expirydate = '2015-05-15'`

Comment: You can click undelete. You can see recently deleted posts by clicking deleted recent questions when listing all posts/Qs/aAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a partition on the month and day that an account cycles will get your desired results:

```
SELECT Region, 
       SubmissionNumber, 
       PolicyNumber, 
       LAG(MasterPolicyNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber, Region, FORMAT(EffectiveDate,'MMdd')  ORDER BY EffectiveDate) as Prior_MasterPolicyNumber, 
       MasterPolicyNumber, 
       LEAD(MasterPolicyNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber, Region, FORMAT(EffectiveDate,'MMdd') ORDER BY EffectiveDate) as  Next_MasterPolicyNumber, 
       NewRenewal, 
       EffectiveDate, 
       ExpiryDate, 
       Coverage, 
       InsuredName
FROM #mytable
ORDER BY Region DESC, PolicyNumber, EffectiveDate
```

There are some questions though:

- Do accounts really always cycle on the same day, and is there never a gap between active cycles?  (ie. they don't renew for two weeks)
- Are there really no cases where a given policy number could have two accounts cycling on the same day?

If cycles can change, or multiple accounts can have the same cycle day, then this falls apart.  And if that is the case, I really don't think it's possible to achieve your goal with account numbers to differentiate policies.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Your code pretty much works. So I see for few accounts, it is like e.g EffectiveDate of current(2016-09-03)  = ExpiryDate (2016-09-04). It's like one day less. Any thoughts on how to map these differences as well ?

Comment: Included the snap of the sample in the above question

Comment: @katy89 You could try changing the partition to only month, `FORMAT(EffectiveDate,'MM')`, but then you're *really* running the risk of having multiple accounts that cycle in the same month with the same policy number.

Comment: IS there somehow I can do use ifelse within the lag function to use either MM or MMDD ?

Comment: @katy89 I can't think of any way to do it that wouldn't open doors for other issues...  The main problem being that one policy number could have dates 2016-09-03 and 2017-09-04 that should belong together, but also dates like 2016-09-27 and 2017-09-27 that belong to another account.  Unfortunately with the lack of account number, your source table does not have what is needed to make a fully reliable query for this...  Maybe some long `UNION` procedure that interrogates each possibility like the one I just mentioned, but even then it would be near impossible to identify all of them perfectly.